# HDInsight MapReduce in C# on a Linux cluster

Tags: c#, azure, azure-hdinsight

How can I write/upload C# Map-Reduce code to a Linux cluster on Azure?

How can I then execute it against an HBase database?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you wish to use C# for your Map-Reduce executing in Linux, you will require to deploy Mono on your Linux Nodes. Following link of our friends of Criteo should be useful.
http://labs.criteo.com/2014/09/running-c-linux-hadoop-cluster

HBase natively supports REST for non-Java languages, such as C#. So you may use HttpWebRequest to interact with the REST API, or adapt the Microsoft HBase REST Client Library for .NET (https://github.com/hdinsight/hbase-sdk-for-net) for Mono/Linux

Hope this helps
Have a nice week-end
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: Mono seem to be already installed; I have seen the link and it shows how to use C# for file MapReduce, but I am still confused on how to use it with HBase, if I do it from C# how can it use Hadoop's distribution?